# Given $f(x)= 2x^2 -x+2$, find and simplify $\frac{f(x+h)-(x)}{h}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My solution to this problem is $x^2+h-2/x(x=h)$

Am I right?

Also, for a deeper understanding of this problem, one should always view the difference quotient as the input? Correct?

Comment: Did you mean $\;\left(f(x+h)-f(x)\right)/h\;$ ?

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)=2x^2-x+2$ then $f(x+h)=2(x+h)^2-(x+h)+2=2x^2+(4h-1)x+2h^2-h+2$.

Therefore $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{2x^2+(4h-1)x+2h^2-h+2-x^2+x-2}{h}=\frac{4hx+2h^2-h}{h}=4x+2h-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this:
$$
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}?
$$
and was your function:
$$
f(x)=2x^2-x+2?
$$
If so, then
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}&=\frac{2(x+h)^2-(x+h)+2-(2x^2-x+2)}{h}\\
&=\frac{2(x^2+2hx+h^2)-x-h+2-2x^2+x-2}{h}\\
&=\frac{2x^2+4hx+2h^2-h-2x^2}{h}\\
&=\frac{4hx+2h^2-h}{h}\\
&=4x+2h-1.
\end{align}
$$

$$\\$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$